How Can I Easily Model Machine-Thread on a Cylinder?
I am modeling valve cap for my car radiator, but I am struggling with the lower part of it (thread). What would be the easiest method to shape this thread?

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

What have you tried as far? Can you edit the question and share some screenshots of your attempts so it's clearer what exactly it is that you are struggling with?  Adding a meaningful title would also increase your chances of getting good help.
